# Apache RedirectMatch, which regex to ignore if a keyword is in the URL

Tags: regex, apache

Apache RedirectMatch, which regex to ignore in some cases?

Hi everyone,

I have a RedirectMatch that allows me to redirect domain-one.com to domain-two.com based on the language parameter in the URL.

For example :

> https://**domain-one.com**/en/*

-->

> https://**domain-two.com**/en/*

I use this Apache condition:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'domain-one.com'">
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/(.*)$ https://**domain-two.com**/en/$1
</If>
```

I would like to know what Regex I should put to **ignore this redirect if a very specific keyword is in the base url**, for example :

> https://domaine-one.com/en/**connect**/*

I tried this expression and it works, but only if the URL ends with "connect", it does not work if the URL is for example "**/en/connect/page1**" :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!.*connect$)(.*)$ https://domain-two.com/$1
```

I don't want to redirect if the word "connect" is present in the URL.

I'm not an expert in Regex I admit...

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot in advance